# Call 3rd party function(Unlayer) from Blazor Server App

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side

I tried to call a 3rd party function(Unlayer) using a js file in Blazor Server App. and it doesn't return any value(null). I tried also to put the return inside exportHtml and use string in InvokeAsync but no luck. Any ideas? Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to `await Task.Delay(5000)`, or `OnAfterRenderAsync`

Comment: Where are you calling the `GetHTML` method from?

Comment: I am calling the GetHTML in a razor page. I am using a Blazor Server App

Comment: Sorry Umair. I am getting the value but I the function should call twice. Is it something about the lifecycle? Or my code are wrong? Thank you.